# how to install opencv and run first program in anaconda3 5.0.0 python 3.6.2 version?

Tags: opencv3.0, python-3.6

I tried using

```
pip install opencv-python
```

It says to not break the installation rules and that I should use the `conda` command. How to install opencv and run first program on it in anaconda3 5.0.0 and python 3.6.2?

Comment: Have you tried the `conda` command? What is your question? I do not see a QUESTION MARK `?` in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Ideall you shouldn't mix conda installed and pip installed packages - it confuses the dependencies when it comes to updates. Although you can use `pip install opencv-python` and opencv will work perfectly well within anaconda.

Instead you need to select opencv3 (assuming you want v3) from a specific repository

`conda install -c menpo opencv3`

ps. I don't know why it isn't included as standard and why have to know/search for the specific repository!